# AWS (or others) vs VPS

Tags: performance, hosting, hosting-recommendation

Currently, we are running our WP based website at dedicated OVH web hosting with the highest performance. Due to fact that traffic at our website continuously grows, we are about to migrate to the dedicated solution and here is where my doubts come.

While searching for WP HA tutorials I found 2 main approaches - self hosted VPS (with own instance of MySQL and Apache) or predefined hosting using images for WP like AWS or Docker.

Which solutions will be performing better? Of course, the question is a bit generic therefore let's assume that money is not a subject so we could invest in both - high AWS plan as well as strong VPS machines.

And second question for those who use AWS - how reliable is this solution? Do you encounter downtimes? Our monitoring shows that OVH is having issues every few days for 10-15 mins.

Answer (score 1):

I monitor a few websites with pingdom, one of the sites I monitor is not mine but I monitor out of curiosity is a amazon hosted site. In the past 6 months it has had 3 hours of downtime and 2 hour of that is in one chunk, apart from the it just went off for a minute at a time. It's always constantly fast. I have not server admin skills but if did I would definitely start hosting sites on Amazon.

Comment: This must be the hurricane Irma :) 3hours.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be a little too anecdotal. Someone answers "never had a second of downtime with AWS" someone answers "they had us down for days". Both might be true and you don't really get useful information.

I would break down things you need to consider like following:

1. Which *skills* do you have on hand. It often sounds like everyone adores messing with servers, but in reality plenty of people (like me) don't. If you just dump managing a VPS on someone who isn’t particularly apt or happy about that — both them and the sites are going to have a bad time.
2. How much reliability do you *really* need. Because if you need a lot you would need not *just* cloud, but possibly multi–region cloud with geographical fault tolerance and such. Or you might be perfectly fine with single server at a solid provider and some minutes of downtime here and there.
3. How much WP hosting know–how do you have/want. Some hosts are happy to give you performance toys (like reverse proxy) which are already fine–tuned for WP and their environment. With others you are completely on your own for that stuff.

Comment: 1. That's the issue, we do have skills to do it ourselves using VPS question is whether it's worth it and what's the gain?  
2. We definately don't need active-active solution, it's just a matter of stability, 99% would do the job (vs 99,999% etc) 
3.  Again, we are experienced developers 

To sum up - we can do it ourselves but I was hoping that someone who has done that in the past could give us some comparison...

Comment: This is a little bit like asking "which car is better". There are a lot of different cars for different purposes. As I said — skills and resources matter a lot here. In my opinion if you already _know_ how to run VPS then scaling to larger server is easier than learning new system. But of course it also matters what you _need_ upgrade to accomplish as well.